# Invoice billing Serial Number automatic generation for each html form using Codeigniter2.2.6

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, serial-number

My problem was about invoice billing generation and for every form, it should generate the new invoice number such as 001 for form1 and it not repeat while next generating billing should come as 002. I have tried some other codes but still not getting. any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Add autoincrement in DB table.

Comment: I don't need to add auto increment in table I need self-increment in the generation of table @urfusion

Comment: After saving invoice if you are saving that in DB then pick that number from DB and increment by 1 to use.

Comment: kk let me try yar and results i will say soon

Comment: hi  @urfusion i have getting serials numbers now based on records counts but in case i delete the some records again it repeats some same numbers while count base now what can i do for it yar and how can i select only last record number in database.

Comment: use limit to get last record.

Comment: Working like charm .thank you so much giving ideas buddy @urfusion

Comment: @urfusion I have another problem am submitting the 10 records of customers at a time means one time of submission it inserts data as row by row in the database but i need that 10 records customer id auto-generation how it is possible can u give the solution, please.

Comment: get last insert id each time a record save in DB and autoincrement that for next record. `$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();`

Comment: hi @urfusion  i have these  two type of queries but i don't know how to replace and retrieve the i mean ids function ops_billing($data,$cust_id) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('op_billing', $data);
}
function visitor_count() {

    $query = $this->db->query("select * from cust_billing order by cust_id DESC limit 1");
    $res=$query->result_array();
 return $res;
} please tell the things i need to arrange

Comment: how to get in controller and how to print in view page yar these things through  insert_id()  @urfusion